# Bash script variable not being passed via ssh

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which ssh's to a server, and depending on the status of a variable performs a task:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo=$1
ssh user@host.com '
echo In host
if [ "$foo" == "yes" ]; then
   echo "Foo!"
fi
'
```

When I run `sh script.sh yes`, although the `ssh` command works, the conditional evaluates to false. I can see this if I `echo $foo` - it prints an empty line. How can I access the value of `foo` within the `ssh` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables aren't transferred to a remote machine. You can expand the variable in the code sent through ssh, but you have to be extremely careful because it opens the door to uncontrolled code execution:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo=$1
ssh user@host.com '
echo In host
if [ "'"$foo"'" == "yes" ]; then
   echo "Foo!"
fi
'
```

Now imagine (don't try) what happens if `foo='$(rm -rf /)'`.